# Azure Service Bus Queue Listener - NodeJs

Tags: node.js, azure, azureservicebus

I have already researched but could not find how to create an Azure Service Bus queue listener in Nodejs.

The only way I found so far is to use the Microsoft Azure SDK for Node.js to request message by message to the queue which is not cost efficient. Any help will be appreciated.

```
sbService.receiveQueueMessage(queueName, { isPeekLock: true }, function(err, lockedMessage) {

    if (err) {
        if (err === 'No messages to receive') {
            console.log('No messages');
        } else {
            callback(err);
        }
    } else {
        callback(null, lockedMessage);
    }
});
```

Comment: check this sample, it uses a setinterval to create a listener: https://github.com/Azure/azure-sdk-for-node/tree/master/lib/services/serviceBus

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For your scenario, I would recommend using [Azure Functions](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-functions/functions-overview) which provides a Service Bus Queue Trigger that enables you to connect your code to other Azure services or on-premises services by listening to message queues. For more information, see [Service Bus bindings](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-functions/functions-bindings-service-bus).

[image]

Comment: that can solve my problem, I will just wait to see if anyone else has a solution that I can use to listen to queue without need to create the Azure function.

Answer (score 0):

As @aaron-chen said, simplest solution will be to use [Azure Function](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-functions/functions-reference-node) with a Servicebus trigger (no extra boring code...)

If you can't use [Azure Function](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-functions/functions-reference-node), you can use the [azure sdk for node.js](https://github.com/Azure/azure-sdk-for-node), I've found this [sample](https://github.com/Azure/azure-sdk-for-node/tree/master/lib/services/serviceBus) form their repo to create a listener:

```
var azure = require('azure-sb');

function checkForMessages(sbService, queueName, callback) {
    sbService.receiveQueueMessage(queueName, { isPeekLock: true }, function (err, lockedMessage) {
        if (err) {
            if (err == 'No messages to receive') {
                console.log('No messages');
            } else {
                callback(err);
            }
         } else {
             callback(null, lockedMessage);
         }
    });
}

function processMessage(sbService, err, lockedMsg) {
    if (err) {
        console.log('Error on Rx: ', err);
    } else {
        console.log('Rx: ', lockedMsg);
        sbService.deleteMessage(lockedMsg, function(err2) {
            if (err2) {
                console.log('Failed to delete message: ', err2);
            } else {
                console.log('Deleted message.');
            }
        })
    }
}

var idx = 0;
function sendMessages(sbService, queueName) {
    var msg = 'Message # ' + (++idx);
    sbService.sendQueueMessage(queueName, msg, function (err) {
        if (err) {
            console.log('Failed Tx: ', err);
        } else {
            console.log('Sent ' + msg);
        }
    });
}

var connStr = process.argv[2] || process.env.CONNECTION_STRING;
if (!connStr) throw new Error('Must provide connection string');
var queueName = 'sbqtest';

console.log('Connecting to ' + connStr + ' queue ' + queueName);
var sbService = azure.createServiceBusService(connStr);
sbService.createQueueIfNotExists(queueName, function (err) {
    if (err) {
        console.log('Failed to create queue: ', err);
    } else {
        setInterval(checkForMessages.bind(null, sbService, queueName, processMessage.bind(null, sbService)), 5000);
        setInterval(sendMessages.bind(null, sbService, queueName), 15000);
    }
});
```